# I have a current function that needs to be changed to the description that I provided

Tags: python

```
def RGB2int(RGB):
    return RGB[0]*256*256 + RGB[1]*256 + RGB[2]
#
def int2RGB(i):
    return (i//(256*256), (i//256)%256, i%256)
#create a function that differentiates between colors

def colordiff(color1,color2):
    color1_int = RGB2int(color1)
    color2_int = RGB2int(color2)
    return int2RGB(color1_int-color2_int)
```

The formula you should use for your modified colordiff function, the difference color between color1 and color2, is as follows.  (Note: these are formulas, not Python!)

If color1 has RGB values R1, G1, B1, respectively,
and color2 has RGB values R2, G2, B2, respectively,
then colordiff has RGB values Rdiff, Gdiff, Bdiff, respectively,
where Rdiff = |R1-R2|, Gdiff = |G1-G2|, Bdiff = |B1-B2|
Note: |x| is the absolute value of x

Comment: This looks like homework. Whats currently wrong with your code?

Comment: Im unable to change my colordiff function to the wanted formula. There are too many variables and I cannot get it to work. Can I have assistance with this?

Comment: You need not convert your rgb triplet to an integer value. You just need to take the difference of each the 3 colour values. So `abs(color1[0]-color2[0])` gives you the value for RDiff (difference of red). Then just do the same for the other two. Also note you need to use [`abs`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#abs) to get an absolute (non-negative) value.

Comment: where do I insert these abs(color1[0]-color2[0])? I am confused because I try to make them a comma list such as

Comment: return int2RGB(abs(color1[0]-color2[0]),abs(color1[2]-color2[2]),abs(color1[3]-color2[3])) but there are not in the tuple range?

Comment: You can just get rid of int2RGB. What you have there is sufficient. It depends what your expected output value will be?

Comment: I am trying to compare 2 images and print out the difference. I have the original colordiff() equation, that I now need to make more useful by using RGB. I am not sure where to add the code you are talking about

Comment: I end up calling on the function like pixeldiff = colordiff(pixel1, pixel2) to compare the pixles.

Answer (score 0):

```
colordiff = lambda x, y: abs(x-y)

color1 = (10, 50, 50)
color2 = (150, 0, 25)

color3 = [*map(colordiff, color1, color2)]
print(color3)
```

Output:

```
[140, 50, 25]
```